# How can I do tooltips in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How can I do this tooltip in Compose?

[image]

Comment: the above screenshot seems like a material showcase view rather then a simple tool tip, if you want to achieve the exact results as shown in the ss, you could use any of the compose showcase view library available on github, do let me if you need anything else.

Comment: use skydoves library, [link] (https://github.com/skydoves/Balloon)